# Batch or VB Script to copy logs from multi directories to one directory and rename to avoid conflicts

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

Hope you can help. I have been trying to resolve this for a week but not getting anywhere and can't quite piece together what I need! - My scripting skills are far from great so please forgive my naivety!
**Ok, The Problem......**
I have an IIS server that has multiple sites that all save their logs in a separate directory, I need to copy the logs from the last 24 hours to a local directory on my machine so I can analyse these in Log Parser Lizard (GUI Version) on a daily basis.
I can map a drive from the remote server to my local machine via a hardware VPN, so this makes things a bit easier. Using the forfiles command I can re-curse the directories to find the logs that are only a day old, and using either copy/xcopy/ or Robocopy I can set a command to copy. My problem is that the IIS logs all have the same name so my copy command just keeps overwriting the previous file, rather than creating a new file. I have tried using the %random% parameter for the file name, but this again creates one random file that is overwritten with the next file, keeping the same name instead of creating lots of randomly named files in one directory.
I know that Log Parser commands include recurse, which I have used successfully, however the format of the log is changed slightly and the GUI Lizard cannot read the data within, so this is not a solution.
My code as it stands at this time is shown below, with IP's changed for obvious reasons. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

@echo off

NET USE Q: /Delete /yes

NET USE Q: \255.255.255.255\D$\Logs

cd C:

RD /S /Q C:\Weblogs\Production

MD C:\Weblogs\Production

forfiles.exe /p Q:\ /s /m *.log /d 0 /c "cmd /c robocopy /S /XC /XN /XO @file C:\Weblogs\Production\%random%.log"

NET USE Q: /delete

exit

Answer (score 0):

`%RANDOM%` does not work for you in this case because it does not get solved per each iteration but only once at the forfiles invocation.

You'll need either to use in `FORFILES` some unique identifier, maybe concatenating `@RELPATH` and `@FNAME` may work for you in case you have only one level deep recursion.

Or either replace `FORFILES` with a `FOR` loop. Inside the loop you may have more freedom to calculate a unique ID, maybe a simple counter might work for you.

**Edit:** see this simple code sample, to get you started

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET destdir=C:\LOGS
SET count=%RANDOM%
FOR /R %%A IN (*.log) DO (
  SET /A count += 1
  @ECHO COPY %%A !destdir!\%%~nA.!count!.log
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! - I had seen the FOR command and thought that would probably be more appropriate, but I am still struggling with how to script this? - Do I use the FOR command to also recurse the directories and find files within the date range as well as renaming them. I have tried to get some more info from the net, but am struggling; getting a bit confused with tokens and delims! - Any further clarification or example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried with FOR? what problems you had? just a hint to get you started... `FOR /R %%A IN (*.log) DO @ECHO %%A %%~tA` see my Edit to the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! - A bit of a late reply I know, but this job got put to one side for a while and I have just started re-visting it. I have now managed to get a working resolution based on the script you provided.